# Google places API returns rating for properties searched using property name, but not with an address

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I am using a Google Places API to return ratings for an entered property. When I enter the property name as the search term, a rating is returned, but if I attempt to return a rating by using an address (which is supported by the text input) I do not receive a response. I have tried searching an address through the API, returning a Place ID and then using the Place ID to return a rating, but that does not work.

This API returns a rating: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=The+Shops+At+Chestnut+Hill&inputtype=textquery&fields=rating&key=[MY API_KEY]`

This is the same property, but searched by address, which does not: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=199+Boylston+St+Chestnut+Hill+MA&inputtype=textquery&fields=rating&key=[MY API_KEY]`

Is there something different with the formatting of address inputs I am not doing correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps details API does not return fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58204065/google-maps-details-api-does-not-return-fields)

Answer (score 0):

The places API has separate ids for the address/building and the establishment in it.  The address/building won't have the rating, the place/establishment will.

From [the PlaceId Finder](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)

> The Shops at Chestnut Hill
>   Place ID: ChIJkcWRbZF444kRJUJjXdUFIOw

> 199 Boylston St
>   Place ID: ChIJ4TgqFZF444kR2XHKhTgsiNs

(although I do see an entry in the dropdown for the "place" when I enter the address)

The Places API `nearbySeach` only returns places, not address place ids. The geocoder returns the place_id of the address. But the `nearbySearch` takes a set of coordinates, not an address, so to get those results from an address requires two calls, one to geocode the address, one to get the `nearbySearch` results from that location.

Note that there are multiple results at the location of that address (4 exactly at the location returned from geocoding "199 Boylston St Chestnut Hill MA", and 15 other places that are nearby and in the footprint of "The Shops at Chestnut Hill"), more if you use pagination to get more than 20 results.

Comment: Is there a way to return the place/establishment at the address with the address versus the name?

Comment: addressed in the answer